# Angular - event: HttpProgressEvent Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: angular

I have this code in Angular-14:

```
  download = () => {
    this.mandateService.getMandateDocument(this.documentId).subscribe((event) => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
        this.progress = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.message = 'Download success.';
        this.downloadFile(event);
      }
    });
  }
```

I got this error:

> (parameter) event: HttpProgressEvent Object is possibly 'undefined'

**angular** is highlighted.

How do I get it sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a reproducible example and not just code fragments.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to put both "if" statements in one additional "if" statement that checks the event. Just like that: "...subscribe ((event) => {if (event) {... your code ...}})"